# Highcharts size doesn't change on div.animate()

Tags: html, css, highcharts, jquery-animate

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="chartDiv">
    <div id="chartContainer"></div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.chartDiv {
    position: absolute;
    height: 1280px;
    width: 720px;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
#chartContainer {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

I have a Highchart initiated by:

```
$("#chartContainer").highcharts({
    ....
});
```

Now I want to change the size and position of chartDiv using:

```
$(".chartDiv").animate({
    top: "100px",
    left: "100px",
    width: "640px",
    height: "360px"
)};
```

As expected, chartContainer changes its size accordingly but the Highcart remains the same size. I interpret it that it will automatically change to its parent size if nothing else is declared but so is not the case. Is it due to using .animate that the chart doesn't react? Ideally, the chart will animate with its parent since chartDiv has borders too it will look bad if it animates first and then the chart (which isn't even the case now).

Answer (score 2):

As you discovered, Highcharts visualizations can be tricky to resize, and the `reflow()` function is not always a helpful or suitable solution.

I'm not sure if you noticed, but the chart **does** reshape to its containing div if you resized your browser window. What you want to do in your case is mimic Highcharts' native ability to resize this way.

In your `animate` function, I added a `setSize()` function to basically reset the chart to the new dimensions of your containing div.

```
$(".chartDiv").animate({
    top: "100px",
    left: "100px",
    width: "640px",
    height: "360px"
}, function () {
    $('#chartContainer').highcharts().setSize(
        $(".chartDiv").width(), // new width of the containing div
        $(".chartDiv").height(), // new height of the containing div
        false // don't animate the chart itself changing
    );
});
```

Here's a working version of your code on JSFiddle (based on one of the Highcharts demos) that shows how this works: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/02hr0wqs/

I hope this helpful for you!

> **Update (July 18, 2016)**: Per the original poster's comment on my answer, I've added a parameter of `false` in `setSize()` to prevent the chart itself from animating when its resized. You can also add an integer as the second parameter in `animate()`, right after you declare the top, left, etc. dimensions and before the function that contains `setSize()`, to adjust the animation of the containing div element.

Comment: That is actually working, thanks. Though one problem is that it happens sequentially, making the chartDiv (with borders) resize first, then the Highchart, which looks off especially when going the other way around and increasing the sizes.

Comment: @simtaxman I made an adjustment, both in my fiddle and my answer above, that should hopefully reduce that dissonance in the animation. Let me know if this is useful.

Comment: It works when shrinking the size but not when making it bigger. Then, the div becomes bigger before the chart animates. Since I have a shadow on the div I want them both to animate simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the elements in browser dev tools, you'll find that highcharts is setting inline styles. In order to override them with external CSS, you'll need to take out your "!important" stick. To change the size of the internal div created by highcharts with its inline determination of height and width, it will need to be targeted directly and the new values will need "!important" to override the opening values highcharts calculates.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the updated solution on this http://jsfiddle.net/devanshumadan/jqqz6vvm/6/

```js
var seriesData = null;

setTimeout(function(){
 $(".chartDiv").animate({
    top: "100px",
    left: "100px",
    width: "640px",
    height: "360px"
});
}, 10000);

setInterval(function(){
console.dir($('#chartContainer').highcharts().series);
seriesData = [((Math.random() * 30) + 1), ((Math.random() * 30) + 1), ((Math.random() * 30) + 1), ((Math.random() * 30) + 1), ((Math.random() * 30) + 1), ((Math.random() * 30) + 1), ((Math.random() * 30) + 1), ((Math.random() * 30) + 1), ((Math.random() * 30) + 1), ((Math.random() * 30) + 1), ((Math.random() * 30) + 1), ((Math.random() * 30) + 1)];
var chart = $('#chartContainer').highcharts();
        chart.series[0].setData(seriesData, false);
$('#chartContainer').highcharts().redraw();
}, 5000);

$(function () {
    $('#chartContainer').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }]
    });   
    
});
```

```css
.chartDiv {
    position: absolute;
    height: 1280px;
    width: 720px;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
#chartContainer {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div class="chartDiv">
    <div id="chartContainer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This I've tried and it doesn't work though. Nothing happens with the charts. And as I understand it, reflow should be true if nothing else is stated, hence resizing when the parent div resizes.

Comment: So this creates the chart after resizing right? The problem is if I want to change the information in the chart with certain intervals, but change the size in another interval without them interfering each other. If I create the chart when resizing I will not see all the charts that are displayed in certain intervals.

Comment: This helps thank you, though it becomes problematic if the intervals are different from each other.

Comment: Cool :)
Let me know if you need more help on this.